# What memory module is compatible with Apple MacBook Pro 13"

Tags: mac, macbook

Obviously it's **Apple MB786G/A**, but does other, less expensive modules do? Apple says simply: any 1Gb, 2Gb or 4Gb PC3-8500 module will do, but I've just tried it with Kingston KVR1066D3S7/2G and have failed. Is there a list for that?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking compatible memory at the [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com) site.
Look at [**Crucial Mac Memory upgrades**](http://www.crucial.com/uk/mac/index.aspx) page (and the [Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/uk/systemscanner/)).

<sup>Is this the correct link? [Apple MacBook Pro 2.53GHz Intel Core 2 Duo (13-inch DDR3)](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=MacBook+Pro+2.53GHz+Intel+Core+2+Duo+%2813-inch+DDR3%29+MB991LL/A+Mid-2009&mfgr=Apple)</sup>

Comment: Hoverer correct link is:

http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=MacBook%20Pro%202.26GHz%20Intel%20Core%202%20Duo%20%2813-inch%20DDR3%29%20MB990LL/A%20Mid-2009&pl=Apple&cat=RAM